# Inverted Index System using Python

Tags: python, information-retrieval, inverted-index

I am working on building an inverted index using Python.

I am having some doubts regarding the performance it can provide me.

Would Python be almost equally as fast in indexing as Java or C?

Also, I would like to know if any modules/implementations exists (and what are they, some link please?) for the same and how well do they perform compared to the something developed in Java/C?

I read about this guy who optimized his Python twice as fast as C by using it with Psyco.

I know for a fact that this is misleading since gcc 3.x compilers are like super fast. Basically, my point is I know Python won't be faster than C. But is it somewhat comparable? 
And can someone shed some light on its performance compared with Java? I have no clue about that. (In terms of inverted index implementation, if possible because it would essentially require disk write and reads.)

I am not asking this here without googling first. I didn't get a definite answer, hence the question.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you are expected to see *much* difference between languages for inverted index, since the bottle neck there is usually IO [disk access!]

If you want some existing implementations that help you to index information, have a look at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) for java and its python version: [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/)

Comment: Indeed very true. But is it the case that Java has a faster IO than Python? (C obviously does.) If yes/no, then to what level? and isn't PyLucene merely a wrapper around the Java version? the IO is essentially still being carried off by the java part. Isn't it?

Comment: @Sylar: IO is specific implementation, and is dependend on the OS and HardWare much more then it is on the language of implementation, AFAIK. And yes, PyLucene is only wrappers for the original lucene. Unless you need something very specific - I'd use it as much as possible, it will cut off development time, and lucene is much more bug-free then ant implementation you will make, due to the wide usage of it, and constant testing by many users.

Comment: Just to remember that indexing documents have a great deal of tokenizing, cleaning and filtering text. But the bottle neck is usually IO (if you're indeed writing to disk). You can check indexing performance with this tiny implementation in scala (JVM): https://github.com/felipehummel/TinySearchEngine Note that search perfomance is bad because it computes some things on-the-fly (that otherwise would be stored).

Answer (score 4):

Worry about optimization after the fact. Write the code, profile it, stress test it, identify the slow parts and offset them in Cython or C or re-write the code to make it more efficient, it might be faster if you load it onto PyPy as that has a JIT Compiler, it can help with long running processes and loops.

Remember

> Premature optimization, is the root of all evil. (After threads of course)

Comment: I am not worrying about optimizations, Knuth ;) 
I am just curious of the fact how well it would perform against Java or C. I am anyways going to do it. Asked out out of pure curiosity!